# How to create calender events in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

In one of my project,I would like to create calender events.I am using Yii framework.

Is there any extension available for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try implementing:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jqeventcalendar/
Or this
https://github.com/edofre/yii2-fullcalendar-scheduler
Or maybe those

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/flowing-calendar/  
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/advance-calender/  
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/fullcalendar/
```

Comment: Thanks @g9m29 I will try this out

Comment: Can you please mark the answer as sufficient. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually I need it for Yii1.1 not for Yii2

Comment: The first one is easily added to Yii 1.1

Comment: I edited my post and add 3 more lines. Sorry that they are in such way but the textarea kept poping up errors for not properly formated code

Comment: Thank you @g9m29.Useful links